# co_await is not supported in coroutines of type std::experimental::generator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

What magic generator should I define to make the code below work?

```
#include <experimental/generator>

std::experimental::generator<int> generateInts()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        co_await some_async_func();

        co_yield i;
    }
};
```

with MSVC I get compiler error:

```
error C2338: co_await is not supported in coroutines of type std::experimental::generator
```

EDIT1:

The error goes from its `await_transform`:

```
        template <class _Uty>
        _Uty&& await_transform(_Uty&& _Whatever) {
            static_assert(_Always_false<_Uty>,
                "co_await is not supported in coroutines of type std::experimental::generator");
            return _STD forward<_Uty>(_Whatever);
        }
```

Comment: `std::experimental::generator` is non-standard and as far as I can tell only exists on MSVC. Maybe you should tag `visual-c++` as well? In fact, I have trouble finding any proper documentation for it. It might not be C++20 coroutine related at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is probably that `generator_iterator` can't handle `co_await` because it requires the task to be suspended with `co_yeld`, see the iterator source code:

```
        generator_iterator& operator++()
        {
            m_coroutine.resume();
            if (m_coroutine.done())
            {
                m_coroutine.promise().rethrow_if_exception();
            }

            return *this;
        }
```

Probably some `async_generator` should handle a situation when a task is suspended with `co_await` and the return value is not ready yet, so its `operator++` also suspends in its turn and becomes asynchronous like this:

```
        async_generator_increment_operation<T> operator++() noexcept
        {
            return async_generator_increment_operation<T>{ *this };
        }
```

where `async_generator_increment_operation` is defined as follows:

```
    template<typename T>
    class async_generator_increment_operation final : public async_generator_advance_operation
    {
    public:

        async_generator_increment_operation(async_generator_iterator<T>& iterator) noexcept
            : async_generator_advance_operation(iterator.m_coroutine.promise(), iterator.m_coroutine)
            , m_iterator(iterator)
        {}

        async_generator_iterator<T>& await_resume();

    private:

        async_generator_iterator<T>& m_iterator;

    };

    template<typename T>
    async_generator_iterator<T>& async_generator_increment_operation<T>::await_resume()
    {
        if (m_promise->finished())
        {
            // Update iterator to end()
            m_iterator = async_generator_iterator<T>{ nullptr };
            m_promise->rethrow_if_unhandled_exception();
        }

        return m_iterator;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The stuff in any `experimental` folder is *not* part of C++20. In this case, this appears to be a part of some stuff for the coroutines TS version of `co_await`. However, the feature went through a *lot* of changes during standardization. So Microsoft is giving you a head's-up by giving you a very specific and informative error: you cannot use the C++20 feature with the types in that header (or probably any of the other "experimental" headers).

You'll have to either write your own generator type or use someone else's that is compatible with C++20 coroutines.